# Play an animation from random point in cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Imagine a game with a top-down view. Right from the start there are 10 monsters on the screen. Each one is represented by a `CCSprite` with a continuous `CCAnimation` applied to it.

If I just run animations on all monsters at once with `runAction:[CCAnimate ...]`, they will all animate in sync. The result I want to get is to start every animation at a random point between 0 and its duration. Once an animation reaches its endpoint, it should start from the beginning and proceed as usual, looping forever.

I have not found a way to achieve this result without modifying the cocos2d source code. And still, I can't get appropriate result for both `CCRepeatForever` and `CCSequence` (when I want to loop two or more consecutive animations with. The code for the latter case:

```
CCAnimate *idleAction = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:...];
CCAnimate *moveAction = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:...];

// ...

- (void)playIdleAnimation
{
    [mySprite runAction:
     [CCSequence actions:idleAction,
      [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(playMoveAnimation)],
      nil]];
}

- (void)playMoveAnimation
{
    [mySprite runAction:
     [CCSequence actions:moveAction,
      [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(playIdleAnimation)]
      nil]];
}
```

Note that I cannot use `[CCSequence actions:idleAction, moveAction, nil]` because each of the two actions may be repeated arbitrary number of times before switching to the other one.

I will appreciate any thoughts on the subject. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What about adding a random delay between the actions.. Something like:

```
[self runAction:[CCSequence actions:[CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:arc4random()%5 + 3],idleAction,moveAction,nil]];
```

Comment: The delay will be noticed by a user. This is undesirable.

Answer (score 0):

```
int randomNumber = arc4random()%5;
CGRect frame1 = CGRectMake(0,0,50,50);
CGRect frame2 = CGRectMake(50,0,50,50);
CGRect frame3 = CGRectMake(100,0,50,50);
CGRect frame4 = CGRectMake(150,0,50,50);
CGRect frame5 = CGRectMake(200,0,50,50);

switch (randomNumber) {
case 0:
     // add frames 1,2,3,4,5 to cache
     break;
case 1:
     // add frames 2,3,4,5,1 to cache
     break;
case 2:
     // add frames 3,4,5,1,2 to cache
     break;
// etc etc
}

// run animation forever
```

i think this way of doing it might answer your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented exactly what you need some time ago. Here is the pull-request: - https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone/pull/249

With my changes, you can start SpriteFrame based animations at any point of the animation, both deterministically and randomly.

I am not sure if they finally ended up merging it or not.